# Angular 7 Unit test case for matdialog open method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine, angular-event-emitter

I am getting static null injector error when I am trying to call dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd method in spec file.

my code is below. 
1. Viewer Component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
    import { ModalPopupComponent } from '../shared/modal-popup/modal-popup.component';
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-viewer',
        templateUrl: './viewer.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./viewer.component.less']
    })
    export class ViewerComponent implements OnInit {
        userAwareNessText: string;
        secondsCounter = interval(300000);

        constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.subScribeTimer();
        }
        subScribeTimer(): void {
            this.secondsCounter.subscribe(() => {
                this.askUserAwareness();
            });
        }
        askUserAwareness(): void {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalPopupComponent, {
                width: '250px',
                data: ''
            });

            const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe((returnData: any) => {
                this.userAwareNessText = returnData;
            });
            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
                sub.unsubscribe();
            });
        }
    }
```

2. Modal PopupComponent

   ```
       import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
   import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
   import { CountdownComponent } from 'ngx-countdown';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-modal-popup',
       templateUrl: './modal-popup.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./modal-popup.component.less']
   })
   export class ModalPopupComponent implements OnInit {
       onAdd = new EventEmitter();
       userAwareNessText: string;

       constructor(
           private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalPopupComponent>) { }

       @ViewChild('countdown') counter: CountdownComponent;

       ngOnInit() {
           this.userAwareNessText = 'User is on the screen!!!';
       }

       finishPopUpTimer() {
           this.userAwareNessText = 'User left the screen!!!';
           this.resetTimer();
           this.closePopUp();
           this.toggleParentView();
       }
       resetTimer() {
           this.counter.restart();
       }
       closePopUp() {
           this.dialogRef.close();
           this.onAdd.emit(this.userAwareNessText);
       }
       toggleParentView() {
           this.onAdd.emit(this.userAwareNessText);
       }
   }
   ```

Here is my spec file of viewer component

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { ViewerComponent } from './Viewer.component';
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
    import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';
    import { ModalPopupComponent } from '../shared/modal-popup/modal-popup.component';
    import { CountdownComponent } from 'ngx-countdown';


    describe('ViewerComponent', () => {
        let component: ViewerComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<ViewerComponent>;
        let modalServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialog>;
        let dialogRefSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj(
            {
                afterClosed: of({}),
                close: null,
                componentInstance: {
                    onAdd: (data: any) => of({ data })
                }
            }
        );


        beforeEach(async(() => {
            modalServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalService', ['open']); // , 'componentInstance', 'onAdd'
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ViewerComponent, ModalPopupComponent],
                providers: [
                    { provide: MatDialog, useValue: modalServiceSpy },
                ],
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            })
                .compileComponents().then(() => {
                    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ViewerComponent);
                    component = fixture.componentInstance;
                });
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ViewerComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            modalServiceSpy.open.and.returnValue(dialogRefSpyObj);
        });

        it('should create component', () => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should open popup and close popup', fakeAsync(() => {
            let fixture_modalPopup = TestBed.createComponent(ModalPopupComponent);
            let component_modalPopUp = fixture_modalPopup.componentInstance;
            fixture_modalPopup.detectChanges();
            spyOn(component_modalPopUp, 'onAdd');

            component.askUserAwareness();

            expect(modalServiceSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(component_modalPopUp.onAdd).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(dialogRefSpyObj.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));

    });
```

**I am getting error for below part of code**

```
const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe((returnData: any) => {
                this.userAwareNessText = returnData;
            });
```

Please suggest me how can I pass that portion of my code.

Comment: Can you please the error message you're getting

Comment: `onAdd` is defined as a property in `ModalPopupComponent` as `onAdd = new EventEmitter();` but in you spy object it is defined as a function `onAdd: (data: any) => of({ data })` also similar problem exists on `afterClosed`. it is defined as property in your test `afterClosed: of({})` where it is a function on `MatDialogRef`. your whole test code needs to be reworked.

Comment: @ysf will you please provide me sample code for that?

Comment: if you can provide me a github repo of your setup, i can.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a spy here:

```
spyOn(component_modalPopUp, 'onAdd');
```

Your following stub function that you provided gets overridden

```
componentInstance: {
    onAdd: (data: any) => of({ data })
}
```

And you are not returning an Observable from your spy and hence you cannot subscribe to it.

You can just provide a spy in your stub function like :

```
componentInstance: {
    onAdd: jasmine.createSpy('onAdd')
}
```

And return values in your test cases depending upon use case,

```
it('should open popup and close popup', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component_modalPopUp, 'onAdd');
    dialogRefSpyObj.componentInstance.onAdd.and.returnValue(of({}))
    component.askUserAwareness();
    ...
}));
```

Comment: Hi @Akshay Rana I did what you suggest, then I am getting this 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined'

Comment: Also one more question, I need to provide all dependencies of ModalPopupComponet in Viewer spec file. Is it correct approach?

Comment: Return the value while mocking in that case( onAdd:jasmine.createSpy('onAdd') ), or add the return statement before "modalServiceSpy.open.and.returnValue(dialogRefSpyObj);"

Comment: No, you don't need to provide dependencies for Modal component, as these are the unit tests for Viewer component. Mocking open method should be enough. Are there any dependencies that compiler is asking for?

Comment: as we are creating spy on componet_ModalPopup, that is component of modal popup component, it is asking for all its dependencies

Comment: On which line? It probably is asking for dependencies because you have added it to your declarations array in configureTestingModule, you don't need it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195677/discussion-between-megha-shah-and-akshay-rana).